# In function template, how to determine type of one argument based on another

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-templates

I'd like to implement a function template that takes two arguments, a T* and a T, but where the second argument's type is determined by the first.  Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> void
patch(T *dst, T src)
{
  static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<T>);
  std::byte *p = reinterpret_cast<std::byte *>(&src);
  std::vector newval(p, p + sizeof(src));

  // In the real code, memcpy happens later if a transaciton commits
  std::memcpy(dst, newval.data(), newval.size());
}

int
main()
{
  std::uint16_t u16;
  patch(&u16, 0);  // Fails to compile because 0 is int, not uint16_t
}
```

This code unfortunately fails to compile because the type T to patch cannot be inferred in `patch(&u16, 0)`, because 0 is an int rather than a `std::uint16_t`.  Obviously I could cast the 0 or call `patch<uint16_t>(...)`, but in an ideal world I wouldn't have to.

On the other hand, I can work around the problem if the second argument involves some kind of non-trivial type computation.  For example, the code will compile if I declare the function as:

```
template<typename T> void
patch(T *dst, std::decay_t<T> src) {/*...*/}
```

When I originally asked the question, I implemented the following and believed it didn't work.  I must have made a mistake, however, because as pointed out by the selected answer, it does in fact work:

```
template<typename T> struct sametype {
  using type = T;
};
template<typename T> using sametype_t = typename sametype<T>::type;

template<typename T> void
patch(T *dst, sametype_t<T> src) {/*...*/}
```

My question is what's the minimal transformation one can apply to a template function argument to force its type to be inferred by the type of a different argument to the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of scenario that [`std::type_identity_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is intended to resolve. This transformation creates what's called a *non-deduced context*, which you've requested for your second parameter of type `T`. Unfortunately this type trait wasn't introduced until the C++20 standard.

You can continue to [use the one you've implemented](https://godbolt.org/z/T1Pnhezjx) (which by the way, yes it does compile at least according to godbolt), or if you're using boost, there is a [`boost::type_identity_t<T>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/type_traits/type_identity.hpp) available.

To answer your question directly though, I believe one of the most *minimal* transformations necessary in C++17 would be [this](https://godbolt.org/z/YKb1q5ozY):

```cpp
template<typename T> void
patch(T *dst, std::enable_if_t<true, T> src)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this an acceptable solution?

```
template<typename T, typename U> void
patch(T *dst, U src)
{
  T s = src;
  static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<T>);
  std::byte *p = reinterpret_cast<std::byte *>(&s);
  std::vector newval(p, p + sizeof(T));

  // In the real code, memcpy happens later if a transaciton commits
  std::memcpy(dst, newval.data(), newval.size());
}
```

Comment: I mean I thought of that, but it's not identical semantically, and might result in fewer compiler warnings if there's overflow.  Imagine that T is a standard-layout type with constructors, while U does not have a copy constructor.

Comment: You can use `const U &src` to skip copy.

Comment: But then you suppress potentially useful compiler warnings.  For example, with the other answer, if you write `patch(&u16, 0x10000)`, then both clang++ and g++ give you a warning, whereas yours simply compiles.  Your answer would have been my fallback, but obviously `std::type_identity` or equivalent is the cleanest answer.