# Why doesn't default template type refer to specified type in instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U = T> void f1(T a, U b)
{
  cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
  cout<<typeid(b).name()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  f1<float>(1,2);
}
```

**output**:

> f

> i   ----> why is it int not default float as per template instantiation?

Comment: Because deduction takes priority over default.

Comment: And why is it so? Any duplicate questions to refer?

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but [here's a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66945729/1541563). Someone more familiar with this tag than me might be able to find a better duplicate.

Comment: A "default" is the last resource; used when nothing else is used. Default template types/values are used when (1) the call doesn't explicit the type/value (as you do with `<float>` for the first type) and (2) the type isn't deduced from the argument.

Comment: Why is it so? Because the function argument can always initialize a `U` if its deduced from it. If the `U` is taken from the default argument first as a you think it should, there is no such guarantee anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default template arguments are last resort, and used only when the argument wasn't specified or deduced.

It's specified in [[temp.deduct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5):

> The resulting substituted and adjusted function type is used as the
> type of the function template for template argument deduction. If a
> template argument **has not been deduced** and its corresponding template
> parameter has a default argument, the template argument is determined
> by substituting the template arguments determined for preceding
> template parameters into the default argument. If the substitution
> results in an invalid type, as described above, type deduction fails.
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T, class U = double>
> void f(T t = 0, U u = 0);
>
> void g() {
>   f(1, 'c');        // f<int,char>(1,'c')
>   f(1);             // f<int,double>(1,0)
>   f();              // error: T cannot be deduced
>   f<int>();         // f<int,double>(0,0)
>   f<int,char>();    // f<int,char>(0,0)
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]