# Why doesn't parameter pack expand to correct type?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have a somewhat contrived piece of code:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename... ARGs>
auto construct1(std::function<void(ARGs...)> p, const ARGs &...args) {}

template < typename... ARGs>
auto construct2(std::function<void(int)>     p, const ARGs &...args) {}

int main() {
    auto p = [](int) {};
    construct1<int>(p, 0);
    construct2<int>(p, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler struggling to work out that `ARGs... = { int }` in the first case? The code compiles okay if I assist the compiler by using `std::function<void(int)>` in the signature (second case). In both cases, the compiler has no trouble deducing that `const ARGs&...` should be `const int&`. Using C++17.

GCC:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘construct1<int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&, int)’
   11 |     construct1<int>(p, 0);
      |                         ^
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... ARGs> auto construct1(std::function<void(ARGs ...)>, const ARGs& ...)’
    4 | auto construct1(std::function<void(ARGs...)> p, const ARGs &...args) {}
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:11:25: note:   ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(ARGs ...)>’
   11 |     construct1<int>(p, 0);
      |
```

Clang:

```
main.cpp:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'construct1'
    construct1<int>(p, 0);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (int, type-parameter-0-0...)>' against '(lambda at main.cpp:10:14)'
auto construct1(std::function<void(ARGs...)> p, const ARGs &...args) {}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66945877/1541563)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, `construct1` is taking `std::function` but you're passing lambda. When you make parameter as type `std::function<void(ARGs...)>`, [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is performed to deduce `ARGs` on the function parameter `p` (even template parameter pack is explicitly specified with [template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_template_arguments) it may be extended by template argument deduction if there are additional arguments), which fails because implicit conversion won't be considered in deduction.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude `p` from deduction (see [non-deduced contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts)), e.g.

```
template <typename... ARGs>
auto construct1(std::function<void(std::type_identity_t<ARGs>...)> p, const ARGs &...args) {}
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BqWZ8NhksnT8eW4A)

---

PS: Before C++20 you can make your won `type_identity` easily as:

```
template< class T >
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
template< class T >
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

Comment: Why is template argument deduction performed at all when template arguments are explicitly specified?