# How can I make a template resolve type only by first parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting, typedef

How can I have a function like this

```
template<typename TValue>
TValue GridSnap(TValue Value, TValue Grid)
```

That resolves template type from only the first parameter like this

```
GridSnap(ADouble, AFloat)  => TValue should resolve to double
GridSnap(AFloat,  ADouble) => TValue should resolve to float
GridSnap(AFloat,  AInt)    => TValue should resolve to float
```

basically I don't want to manually cast the second argument, it would be nice if it could just do implicit cast base on the first parameter.

Comment: The type of both the function parameters(`Value` and `Grid`) is `TValue` so the passed arguments `ADouble` and `AFloat` must be of the same type otherwise you'll get error saying conflicting types deduced.

Comment: @JasonLiam that's what I'm trying to avoid without using explicit casts everywhere.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66945877)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I see. So the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589722/12002570) below should solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NathanOliver solution worked nicely, But I also found this solution

```
TValue GridSnapAuto(TValue Value, decltype(Value) Grid)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to have the template parameter of the second function parameter to be in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context).  You can do this using `std::type_identity` like

```
template <typename TValue>
TValue GridSnap(TValue Value, std::type_identity_t<TValue> Grid)
```

If you can't use C++20, then you can just write your own `type_identity` and `type_identity_t` like

```
template <typename T>
struct type_identity 
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, It works. but I found a shorter solution `TValue GridSnapAuto(TValue Value, decltype(Value) Grid)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Nice solution.  Didn't even think of that.  You should post that as an answer.